# error on "first commit"

Tags: git, gitlab

The project is not initialized in gitlab after push "first commit".

```
root@londeron:/var/www/example.com# git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 358 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@git.example.com:user/example.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

After push I watch:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to start some background daemon? Try restarting the service, or clear caches.

Comment: Do you have Sidekiq and Redis running?

Comment: Redis server version 2.4.14 (00000000:0)

Comment: redis-server is running

Comment: How to check Sidekiq ?

Comment: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/02/03/bc1/b67/4ad6fed7bca6ea528c7443013e0f2f9b3e12bfff.jpg

Comment: Maybe you don’t have git hooks inside bare repos?